# Determine the longest word in a text input

Tags: c++

How do I create a program where it reads in text from the user and then outputs the shortest and longest words and how many characters these words contain?

So far, I can only create a program that counts the number of words in the text.

```cpp
int count_words {};
string word;

cout << "Type a text:" << endl;

while (cin >> word)
{
    count_words++;
}
    
cout << "The text contains " << count_words << " words." << endl;
```

Can the loop be manipulated so that it determines the shortest and longest words?

Comment: This should be enough to get you started: [Min and Max Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734407/min-and-max-loop)

Comment: `longest = std::max(longest, word.size());` ought to do the trick, if you define `std::string::size_type longest = 0;` before your loop.

Comment: The OP asked to output the longest word, so it is not enough to just track the size of the longest word, you need to keep track of the actual word itself.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, since your comments on your answer got locked for some reason and I think posting another thread will go against stack overflows policy due to duplicates, I have no other choice than to ask you here.

If I want to determine the shortest word, how do I do that? 
I tried doing the same concept as you did when determining the longest word but instead I get that the shortest word is "" with 0 characters no matter what my input is. 

In the loop I put 

'if (word.size() < shortest_word.size())
shortest_word = word;

Comment: @leun you are not accounting for `shortest_word` being empty iitially, thus `shortest_word.size()` is `0`, so `if (word.size() < shortest_word.size())` is always false.  I have updated my answer with working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply declare a couple of `string` variables, and then inside the `while` loop you can assign `word` to those variables when `word.size()` is larger/smaller than the `size()` of those variable, eg:

```cpp
size_t count_words = 0;
string word, longest_word, shortest_word;

cout << "Type a text:" << endl;

while (cin >> word)
{
    ++count_words;
    if (word.size() > longest_word.size())
        longest_word = word;
    if (shortest_word.empty() || word.size() < shortest_word.size())
        shortest_word = word;
}

cout << "The text contains " << count_words << " word(s)." << endl;
if (count_words > 0) {
    cout << "The shortest word is " << shortest_word << "." << endl;
    cout << "It has " << shortest_word.size() << " character(s)." << endl;
    cout << "The longest word is " << longest_word << "." << endl;
    cout << "It has " << longest_word.size() << " character(s)." << endl;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/3I0kuN)

Alternatively:

```cpp
string word;

cout << "Type a text:" << endl;

if (cin >> word) {
    size_t count_words = 1;
    string longest_word = word, shortest_word = word;

    while (cin >> word) {
        ++count_words;
        if (word.size() > longest_word.size())
            longest_word = word;
        if (word.size() < shortest_word.size())
            shortest_word = word;
    }

    cout << "The text contains " << count_words << " word(s)." << endl;
    cout << "The shortest word is " << shortest_word << "." << endl;
    cout << "It has " << shortest_word.size() << " character(s)." << endl;
    cout << "The longest word is " << longest_word << "." << endl;
    cout << "It has " << longest_word.size() << " character(s)." << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "No text was entered." << endl;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/VdX3ON)